# JBoss authentication when password is encoded by ARGON2id

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly

I have password encrypted by *Argon2id* in database.

How can I change my configuration to let *JBoss* know that it have to use *Argon2* to verify password?

*standalone.xml*

```
<security-domain name="databaseDomain">
                <authentication>
                    <login-module code="Database" flag="required">
                        <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:/datasources/hotel"/>
                        <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="select password from users where login=?"/>
                        <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="SELECT employee.position,'Roles' FROM users, employee WHERE employee.id=users.employeeId and login=?"/>
                        <module-option name="unauthenticatedIdentity" value="guest"/>
                    </login-module>
                </authentication>
            </security-domain>
```

*web.xml*

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.html</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/error.html</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

*jboss-web.xml*

```
 <jboss-web>
<security-domain>databaseDomain</security-domain>
</jboss-web>
```

I added *ARGON2* with

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.mkammerer</groupId>
    <artifactId>argon2-jvm</artifactId>
     <version>2.7</version>
</dependency>
```

I tried adding to *standalone.xml*

```
<module-option name="hashAlgorithm" value="ARGON2id"/>
```

but it didn't work and I wasn't that suprised about this. My form is calling to *j_security_check*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement your own login module, sounds scary, but actually it's not.

1. Find out which version of Picketbox you're Wildfly is bundled with - look in the `modules/system/layers/base/org/picketbox/main` directory. I.e. for WF 21 the version of Picketbox is 5.0.3.Final
2. Add the Picketbox library as a `provided`-scoped dependency to your project
3. Implement your custom login module by extending the `org.jboss.security.auth.spi.DatabaseServerLoginModule` class and overriding the `convertRawPassword` method - this is where you need to convert the user's input into the Argon2 form
4. Provide the full class name in the `code` parameter in your login module configuration in `standalone.xml`. Wildfly will pick it from your deployment and use your implementation instead of the default one.

This should work.